Minimizing a complex system involving differences of logarithms
Problem
Consider the expression (with $i=1,2,3,\cdots n$):
\begin{align}
g_i(z_0, \beta_i) = A\sqrt{\frac{A^{2}}{C^{2}\left(A^{2}-\beta_i^{2}\right)}}\left(\ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{\frac{A+Be^{Cz_{i}}-\beta_i}{A+Be^{Cz_{i}}+\beta_i}}-\sqrt{\frac{A-\beta_i}{A+\beta_i}}}{\sqrt{\frac{A+Be^{Cz_{i}}-\beta_i}{A+Be^{Cz_{i}}+\beta_i}}+\sqrt{\frac{A-\beta_i}{A+\beta_i}}}\right|\right)-\\
\ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{\frac{A+Be^{Cz_{0}}-\beta_i}{A+Be^{Cz_{0}}+\beta_i}}-\sqrt{\frac{A-\beta_i}{A+\beta_i}}}{\sqrt{\frac{A+Be^{Cz_{0}}-\beta_i}{A+Be^{Cz_{0}}+\beta_i}}+\sqrt{\frac{A-\beta_i}{A+\beta_i}}}\right|\right)\right) = t_i  
\end{align}
I have a system of the form:
\begin{align}
g_i(z_0, \beta_i) - g_j(z_0, \beta_j)= 299,792,458 \cdot (t_i - t_j)
\end{align}
Where $A, B, C, z_i$ and the differences $t_i - t_j$ are known (although the individual $t_i$'s themselves are not). I have additionally the following constraint:

$z_i, z_0 < 0$.

I wish to determine the $z_0$ and set $\beta_i$ which solves the system, e.g. that which minimizes:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n |(g_i - g_j) - (t_i - t_j)|^2
\end{equation}

What is this?
The $t_i$ term represents some measured about of propagation time between an unknown point $\langle x_0, y_0, z_0\rangle$ and the known point $\langle x_i, y_i, z_i \rangle$. The remainder is a formula for the propagation time in terms of $z_i, z_0$ and $\beta_i$ (the latter depending in an unknown manner on the known and unknown point, and perhaps also some of the constants present). My end goal is to determine $\langle x_0, y_0, z_0\rangle$. By determining $z_0$ and the set $\beta_i$, I can use other equations to draw intersecting circles with $z$-coordinate $z_0$, which I can then use to determine the unknown point.
The differences $t_i - t_j$ are measured by emitting a signal at the unknown point and measuring its arrival time at instruments positioned at each of the known points. Regrettably, I do not know the time of signal emission, so I do not know the transit time, only the arrival time differences.

What I've Tried
I've tried solving this analytically, however (perhaps unsurprisingly) neither I nor Mathematica can determine an exact solution. I've also tried massaging this system into forms minimize-able by the various minimizers made available by the SciPy library. Each has failed to accurately determine $z_0$ and the set $\beta_i$ using simulated $t_i$ generated using arbitrarily chosen $z_0$ and $\beta_i$ (all reach a "solution", but none are close to the true solution). This is true of both global routines and local routines with initial guesses that aren't quite close to the true solution.
Regrettably, I cannot provide a good initial guess, and so I desire a global minimization routine.
For further context, this is the result of my attempt to make progress on this problem: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/824199/420561
How might I go about performing this minimization?

Addendum
Here's an example SciPy solution, with some example simulated data. I'm using the L-BFGS-B algorithm here, for no particular reason.
from ray_tracer import RayTracer
from random import randrange
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class TimeDifferenceSolver:
    z_i: np.ndarray  # Array of known z_i coordinates
    params: np.ndarray  # Array containing A, B, and C

    def _g(self, z0, beta_i, z_i, A, B, C):
        A, B, C = self.params

        beta = beta_i
        sqrt_term = np.sqrt(A**2 - beta**2)

        term_zi = np.sqrt((C**2 + (C * sqrt_term / beta)**2) / (C**2 * (C * sqrt_term / beta)**2))
        log_argument_zi = np.abs(
            (np.sqrt((A + B * np.exp(C * z_i) - beta) / (A + B * np.exp(C * z_i) + beta)) - np.sqrt((A - beta) / (A + beta))) /
            (np.sqrt((A + B * np.exp(C * z_i) - beta) / (A + B * np.exp(C * z_i) + beta)) + np.sqrt((A - beta) / (A + beta)))
        )
        log_zi = np.log(log_argument_zi)

        first_term_zi = A * term_zi * log_zi

        log_argument_z0 = np.abs(
            (np.sqrt((A + B * np.exp(C * z0) - beta) / (A + B * np.exp(C * z0) + beta)) - np.sqrt((A - beta) / (A + beta))) /
            (np.sqrt((A + B * np.exp(C * z0) - beta) / (A + B * np.exp(C * z0) + beta)) + np.sqrt((A - beta) / (A + beta)))
        )
        log_z0 = np.log(log_argument_z0)

        first_term_z0 = A * term_zi * log_z0

        result = first_term_zi - first_term_z0

        return result/299792458

    def objective_function(self, variables, t_i_values):
        # Extract z_0 and beta_i values from the optimization variable
        z0 = variables[0]
        beta_i = variables[1:]

        A, B, C = self.params
        n = len(self.z_i)

        # Compute the sum of squared differences for all pairs (i, j)
        error_sum = 0
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(i + 1, n):
                g_i_value = self._g(z0, beta_i[i], self.z_i[i], A, B, C)
                g_j_value = self._g(z0, beta_i[j], self.z_i[j], A, B, C)
                error_sum += (g_i_value - g_j_value - (t_i_values[i] - t_i_values[j]))**2

        return error_sum

    def find(self, t_i_values):
        # Initial guess for z_0 and beta_i
        initial_guess = np.ones(len(self.z_i) + 1) * -1  # Starting with z_0 and beta_i all -1 (as z0 and zi < 0)

        # Minimize the objective function
        result = minimize(self.objective_function, initial_guess, args=(t_i_values,), method='L-BFGS-B')
        
        # Extract z_0 and beta_i values from the result
        z0_opt = result.x[0]
        beta_i_opt = result.x[1:]
        
        return z0_opt, beta_i_opt

t_i_examples = [[6.767497217196613e-06, 6.560908657371282e-06, 6.925210333973973e-06, 6.530254888400991e-06, 6.755516813206531e-06, 6.619582551729789e-06, 6.579166768050318e-06, 7.151171380072868e-06, 7.000049368578958e-06, 6.682370044729153e-06], [5.984702539514993e-06, 5.930014598549508e-06, 5.598447335939742e-06, 6.190116484206916e-06, 5.749205253437443e-06, 6.099216577640195e-06, 6.09800253359304e-06, 6.002179216351752e-06, 6.385774539401187e-06, 6.088005634055416e-06], [4.665259457709067e-06, 4.72830311317074e-06, 4.824128899105909e-06, 5.068049986598144e-06, 4.720203892443567e-06, 5.203220656040072e-06, 4.684312194021325e-06, 5.011060151019048e-06, 5.196928493759881e-06, 5.086752131673956e-06], [5.004986255762178e-06, 5.1259407121812555e-06, 5.577304001403536e-06, 4.945493904613105e-06, 5.3276368868484015e-06, 4.984916724948599e-06, 5.504421969627293e-06, 5.086412981784503e-06, 5.0244461591639915e-06, 5.09299975674606e-06]]

z_0_examples = [-528, -679, -781, -877]

z_i_examples = [[-34, -94, -29, -65, -11, -29, -80, -34, -86, -63],
        [-92, -22, -99, -84, -85, -62, -86, -19, -23, -70],
        [-22, -96, -86, -42, -96, -3, -83, -40, -21, -3],
        [-52, -26, -4, -63, -36, -89, -17, -100, -48, -86]]


beta_i_examples = [[1.6396928887135265, 1.6574727386987005, 1.6454327818483134, 1.6418398684695759, 1.6294595761205148, 1.6296247114861102, 1.6515037156116221, 1.65748863574386, 1.6715678081516174, 1.6483391958245628],
           [1.4662909546401228, 1.3834362335899673, 1.4220961871328066, 1.482251553825198, 1.4272665047376376, 1.4498234809191288, 1.4736817069254222, 1.3919204565138836, 1.4497458404733339, 1.4564473325785974],
           [0.5693154689394847, 0.9341213201145733, 0.9509296446353164, 0.9389788567461165, 0.9298062250965199, 0.8975872756256842, 0.8629097820901123, 0.9035389490524869, 0.9435090344661008, 0.831211938974932],
           [0.45239345553514915, 0.4303687193335445, 0.7425426901537331, 0.45295109015203266, 0.685269810976178, 0.6509174325017857, 0.7387590151232529, 0.7763085100137423, 0.44961840753325033, 0.7225205197927285]]


params = np.array([1.78, 0.454, 0.0132])

for i in range(len(z_i_examples)):

    solver = TimeDifferenceSolver(z_i_examples[i], params)
    z0_solution, beta_i_solution = solver.find(t_i_examples[i])

    print(f"True z0: {z_0_examples[i]}")
    print(f"True beta_i: {beta_i_examples[i]}")

    print("Value of objective at 'true' solution:", solver.objective_function(np.insert(beta_i_examples[i], 0, z_0_examples[i], axis=0), t_i_examples[i]))

    print(f"Optimal z0: {z0_solution}")
    print(f"Optimal beta_i: {beta_i_solution}")

    print("Value of objective at optimized solution:", solver.objective_function(np.insert(beta_i_solution, 0, z0_solution, axis=0), t_i_examples[i]))
```


So you have a system like $g_i(z_0,\beta_i)=t_i, (i = 1,\cdots,n)$ and you want to know the best $(z_0,\beta_i)$ which minimizes $\sum_i^n|g_i(z_0,\beta_i)-t_i|^2$ subject to $z_0 <0$?

I see you mentioned SciPy: can you share some code and the input data? How do you recognise a “true” solution?

@Infinity77 I've added an example SciPy solution, as well as some example input data. What this code is intended to do is solve for the depth of an unknown point given measured differences in arrival times of a light signal emitted at this unknown point at sensors located at the known points (the light signal emission time is unknown, so I know only the arrival time differences), as well as the angle made between the horizontal axis and the light ray at each of the known points.

@Infinity77 I've written another script that computes these depth, arrival time, and angle values numerically, given known starting and ending points (i.e. known $x_0, y_0, z_0$ and $x_i, y_i, z_i$). I can then use this to test the code by passing to it the times and points  $x_i, y_i, z_i$, and comparing the found angles and depth coordinate $z_0$ to that which I used to generate the times. I've included some example data in my post. If you like, I could also post the script I use to generate this data (although it is somewhat long and arduous).

@Infinity77 For further context, this is the result of my attempt to make progress on this problem: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/824199/420561

@IntegerEuler: I have just tried your Python code, naively plugging your "True" solution into the objective function, and Python tells me that the return value of your objective function for the "True" values is NaN. This is not surprising as your A parameter is 1.78 while some of your beta_i are > 2, so this line: Omega_i = C * np.sqrt(A ** 2 - beta_i ** 2) / beta_i attempts to take a sqrt of a negative number,

@Infinity77 Sorry about that! I mistakenly posted simulated "true" solutions generated with a much larger A parameter value. I've edited the post with a set of corrected example data. Thanks a ton for your help with this.

@IntegerEuler: I still get NaN in 3 out of the 5 examples (the first 3) by simply calculating the objective function using your values. For all the examples, the objective function I get from L-BFGS-B are: 307, 10^-11, 10^-11, 2312, 6624. The objective functions from the optimal parameters from BFGS are much lower than your "True" ones (when yours exist)

@Infinity77 My apologies again. In an attempt to simplify my code and the expression to be minimized before posting here I seem to have introduced an error somewhere (I'm unfortunately not sure where). I should have vetted the code I posted better before doing so. I've replaced it with a corrected script (you'll see that the value of the objective now evaluates to exactly 0 at the example "true" solutions).

What is $\Omega_i$'s role in all this?

@Cesareo Sorry, that was an artifact from a previous iteration of this question. I've since rewritten the expression  not in terms of $\Omega_i$. I've corrected the post.

Your objective function is very badly scaled and pretty much insensitive to the value of the z parameter - assuming for a moment to take the betas fixed.
This is what happens if I only take the first set of beta_i_examples (i.e., beta_i_examples[0]) and only take the first set of the ti_examples (i.e., ti_examples[0]) but let the z parameter vary between -1,000 and 0 in 10,000 steps:

Note that the scale is logarithmic and the value of the objective function ranges from 10^-44 to 10^-40. So it's basically zero no matter what the z value is.
This also means that your "True" z for the first example (i.e., z = -87) is not really "True", as I get lower values of the objective function for z around -61.
Other than that, there are very many combinations of z and beta (your optimization variables) which make your _g() function return NaN, so any optimizer is going to struggle with that and possibly not recover.
I believe you ill have to find a way to:

Avoid NaN from your _g function - maybe with bounds on variables
Rescale your objective function so that it doesn't return ridiculously small numbers for a wide range of inputs.


Follows an optimization procedure (written in MATHEMATICA) to find $\beta_i$'s and $z_0$ given a set of $\{z_i, t_i\}, A,B,C,\ \ i = 1,\cdots, 10$. The approximation error was chosen as
$$
\max_{i,j} ||g(z_0,z_i,\beta_i)-g(z_0,z_j,\beta_j)|-|t_i-t_j||
$$
The script is self explanatory.
tdata = {7.985654530651264*^-06, 8.210514161430411*^-06, 
         7.897596821083545*^-06, 7.754101835468048*^-06, 
         8.162330603400058*^-06, 7.763458722133717*^-06, 
         8.199412867233405*^-06, 7.856214943947614*^-06, 
         7.898657593691835*^-06, 7.735680631372238*^-06};
z0data = {-969, -485, -1000, -931, -403};
zdata = {-57, -28, -33, -92, -29, -89, -10, -67, -43, -85};
(***
bdata = {1.6396928887135265, 1.6574727386987005,
        1.6454327818483134, 1.6418398684695759,
        1.6294595761205148, 1.6296247114861102,
        1.6515037156116221, 1.65748863574386,
        1.6715678081516174, 1.6483391958245628};
***)
parms = {A -> 1.78, B -> 0.454, c -> 0.0132, ct -> 299792458};

Clear[num, den]
numa[zi_, bi_] := Sqrt[(A + B Exp[c zi] - bi)/(A + B Exp[c zi] + bi)] - Sqrt[(A - bi)/(A + bi)];
dena[zi_, bi_] := Sqrt[(A + B Exp[c zi] - bi)/(A + B Exp[c zi] + bi)] + Sqrt[(A - bi)/(A + bi)];
num[zi_, bi_] := numa[zi, bi]/dena[zi, bi]

numb[z0k_, bi_] := Sqrt[(A + B Exp[c z0k] - bi)/(A + B Exp[c z0k] + bi)] - Sqrt[(A - bi)/(A + bi)];
denb[z0k_, bi_] := Sqrt[(A + B Exp[c z0k] - bi)/(A + B Exp[c z0k] + bi)] + Sqrt[(A - bi)/(A + bi)];
den[z0k_, bi_] := numb[z0k, bi]/denb[z0k, bi]
coef[bi_] := A^2/c /Sqrt[(A^2 - bi^2)]

g[z0_, zi_, bi_] := coef[bi] Log[num[zi, bi]/den[z0, bi]]/ct
bvar = Table[b[k], {k, 1, Length[zdata]}];

Clear[obj]
obj[z0_, z_List, b_List, t_List] := Module[{i, j, s, errmax = 0},
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[z], i++,
   For[j = 1, j <= i, j++,
    If[i != j,
     s = Abs[Abs[g[z0, z[[i]], b[[i]]] - g[z0, z[[j]], b[[j]]]] - Abs[t[[i]] - t[[j]]]] /. parms;
     If[s > errmax, errmax = s]
     ]
    ]
   ];
  Return[ errmax]
  ]

restrs = Join[{z0 < 0}, Table[b[i] > 0, {i, 1, Length[zdata]}]]
sol = NMinimize[{obj[z0, zdata, bvar, tdata], restrs},Join[{z0}, bvar], Method -> "RandomSearch"]

$$
\{0.,\{z_0\to -1.95205,\beta_1\to 0.153073,\beta_2\to 1.31554,\beta_3\to 1.64974,\beta_4\to 1.5414,\beta_5\to
  0.28532,\beta_6\to 0.1659584,\beta_7\to 1.53134,\beta_8\to 0.401868,\beta_9\to 0.534458,\beta_{10}\to 1.32184\}\}
$$
